# How to customize HTTP-500 error page for ServiceStack?

Tags: http, razor, error-handling, servicestack, internal-server-error

I want to customize the error page shown if my ServiceStack app hits an unhandeled Exception and returns a HTTP-500.

I'm using ServiceStack.Razor (http://razor.servicestack.net/) and tried to follow their example (see *Easily configure custom error pages in code*).  This is what I've tried:

AppHost.cs:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    CustomHttpHandlers = {
        { HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new RazorHandler("/ErrorInternal") }
    }
});
```

Views/ErrorInternal.cshtml:

```
An error has occured.
```

But I still get the standard ServiceStack error page "Snapshot of ... generated by ServiceStack on ...".

Answer (score 1):

The cshtml pages under the views folder are used to provide an HTML representation of your response DTOs. What you probably want are the "Dynamic pages without Controllers" for a 500 error. Move your ErrorInternal.cshtml to the root folder of your solution and your "/ErrorInternal" hander should work.